Implementation of PINNs (Physics Informed Neural Networks) in Mathematica
I know Mathematica does not have an Autograd function for differentiating a neural network with respect to its input. Has any one tried an implementation PINNs for solving PDEs in mathematics?
Many thank

Welcome back to Mma.SE. I see it's your second question and you still haven't followed the recommended [tour]. It's important to familiarize yourself with the community expectations, so I also recommend reading [ask] , as the current form of your question is not very specific, and we have a policy against open ended questions, we consider that open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site. Please [edit] your question to make it more specific.

Mathematica does have a way to differentiate a neural network with respect to its input; look up https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetPortGradient.html

As someone pointed out, the statement "Mathematica does not have an Autograd function for differentiating a neural network with respect to its input" is not 100% correct. The NetPortGradient function lets you take the gradient with respect to the input, although only in first order. So, for PINNs, where you usually need to take 2nd + ordered derivatives, that won't work.
One alternative is to use finite difference formulas for the higher-order derivatives and create a separate net to calculate the derivatives. For instance, check out these two posts, that might be of help:
https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2446710
https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2557040
